# How strong lighting should I have in a studio where I work with only paper and pen?

Tags: design-principles, drawing, sketching, paper, fine-arts

I have a studio where I never use a computer. I only work with paper and pencils. How strong lighting (how many Lux) should I aim for if only using ceiling lights (LED at 6000K)?

Is 1000 Lux enough? Too much?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know if there's a standard, each person's eyes and personal preferences are quite different. (for example, I like a room fairly dark, with just enough light from a desk lamp to see what I'm sketching.)

Comment: How big is the room? The light decays at a quick rate as the sphere of its influence grows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say 1000 is enough, it's very bright actually. It's similar to normal daylight and that's what is usually recommended for graphic design on computers as well.

You can go a bit lower for your own comfort and depending on the style of drawing you do; your eyes are probably the best calibrating tool to evaluate contrasts and colors. Unlike working on computers that produce a light as well, you work directly on your artwork and there's less risks of distortion and less intermediary that could make you misjudge the real colors and contrasts of your illustrations.

[image: Lux Wikipedia]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux)</sup>

You might also want to take a look at the kelvin for the color temprature of your light as well. Recommended is 5500K. The color of the light will affect how you see your colors, so this is probably as important as the luminosity in your room.

That's just my experience, but proofing rooms in most print shop where the control of color has to be optimal do not use standard LED lamps because they're usually more "cool white". There's light bulbs (maybe now LED lamps) specially made for the 5500K that can be used for that purpose. In doubt, even standard light bulbs offer a more natural color than any fluorescent or standard LED kind of light. Even though they're more warm white, they're still closest to a natural light at noon.

[image: color and light temperature]

---

**More details on lux and kelvin for design studio:**

http://willkempartschool.com/art-studio-lighting-design/

http://www.seesmartled.com/kb/choosing_color_temperature/